What keywords should I look for finding the cause of hang+reboot?
Since few weeks my system (Ubuntu 23.10) often freezes/hangs and after few seconds reboots (usually, if it happens, it happens in the first minutes after powering up and after it reboots it does not happen anymore that day). The hardware is pretty new (< 6 month) and the temperatures are ok. The happen in any situation, even if I'm not at the computer with no applications running.
I guess I know which log files I have to look, and I read a lot of questions about log files, example:

Where can I find information about the last hang of the system?

Ubuntu freezes. Which logs can I check out?


but those log files are huge!
Even "grepping" for error lead to hundreds of lines and most of them seem not directly related to the hangs.
Here I'm asking which keywords should I look for in the log files to find out the cause of the reboot.
UPDATE
Hardware information:

AMD Ryzen™ 9 7950X
4x VENGEANCE® 16GB DDR5 DRAM 5200MT/s CL40
ASUS ROG STRIX X670E-E GAMING WIFI
NVIDIA GeForce RTX™ 4080
2x Samsung SSD 980 PRO 500GB

The last reboot command shows TWO running items!
$ last reboot
reboot   system boot  6.5.0-26-generic Mon Apr  8 08:22   still running
reboot   system boot  6.5.0-26-generic Mon Apr  8 08:20   still running <--- here it rebooted after a freeze!
reboot   system boot  6.5.0-26-generic Sun Apr  7 16:25 - 19:17  (02:51)
reboot   system boot  6.5.0-26-generic Sun Apr  7 16:17 - 16:25  (00:08) <--- also here
reboot   system boot  6.5.0-26-generic Fri Apr  5 20:47 - 22:37  (01:50)
...

$ last
mark :0           :0               Mon Apr  8 08:22   still logged in
mark seat0        login screen     Mon Apr  8 08:22   still logged in
reboot   system boot  6.5.0-26-generic Mon Apr  8 08:22   still running
mark :0           :0               Mon Apr  8 08:20 - crash  (00:02)
mark seat0        login screen     Mon Apr  8 08:20 - crash  (00:02)
reboot   system boot  6.5.0-26-generic Mon Apr  8 08:20   still running


You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details (know what you're running will narrow down what logs exist), but as some system logs (eg. what you view with dmesg) will not survive a reboot, some do (eg. journalctl can be used to review systemd journals which survive reboots).  Depending on your hardware (you didn't specify), some machines provide clues in the machine logs (usually only enterprise geared hardware esp. servers) that will have answers where it's not the OS that caused reboot.

You can get the reboot time and dates with the command last reboot eventually last reboot | head 10 to see only the last 10.
Then use this to search the logs around that time/date.

@guiverc I'm going to update the question with the hw information

@SorenA interesting enough it shows TWO reboots with the still running note! The very last one is correct, but the previous one is the crash!

@guiverc question updated

Does this answer your question? Ubuntu freezes. Which logs can I check out?

@zwets, no thanks, as said I'm not asking about which log I can check out, but which keyword I should use inside them. Furthermore, I've already put your link inside my own question!
